# Как давно изменились правила склонения имен существительных?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Передо мной книга Д.Э.Розенталя за 1979 год, "Современный русский язык", издательство "Высшая Школа", стр 197, в 1 склонение входят все существительные среднего рода кроме дитя и сущ. на мя. и большинство сущ. мужского рода с нулевым окончанием, на -о-е, и увеличительные с уничижительными суффиксальными образованиями от неодушевленных существительных мужского рода.

Сегодня принято считать, что в 1 склонение входят существительные м.р и ж.р. на -а-я. Хотелось бы узнать, когда и по каким причинам правило склонений сущ. русского языка было изменено.

И нельзя не упомянуть о разносклоняемых существительных и оканчивающихся на -ий-ие-ия. Санаторий. Здание. Станция. По действующим сейчас правилам эти существительные попадают в одно из трех склонений???

Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле правила не менялись.  Различаются академическое склонение и школьное.

К первому школьному склонению **(в академической грамматике – ко второму)** относятся существительные женского, мужского и общего рода с окончанием -а, -я (вода, земля, линия, дядя, сирота).

Ко второму школьному склонению **(в академической грамматике – к первому)** относятся существительные мужского рода с нулевым окончанием (дом, конь, край, шалаш, мяч), кроме слова путь, и все существительные с окончанием -о, -е (окно, поле, увлечение, домишко, волчище).

Что касается разносклоняемых существительных, в школьной практике они не относятся не к какому склонению, т.е. они выделяются в отдельную группу.

Однако в русской грамматике (**АКАДЕМИЯ НАУК СССР
ИНСТИТУТ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА РУССКАЯ ГРАММАТИКА)** к третьему склонению по системе падежных флексий относятся также существительные сред. р. на -мя с флексией в им. п. ед. ч. -|а| (орфогр. -я) (бремя, время, вымя, знамя, имя, пламя, полымя [устар.], племя, стремя, семя, темя), существительные сред. р. дитя и муж. р. путь.

См.: Русский язык. Весь курс. И.Б. Голуб. М.2010 г. Розенталь. Д.Э. Русский язык.Орфография, Пунктуация. М.2002 г.

Answer (score 0):

Я не вижу, что что-то изменилось. Кроме названий, разумеется, это не правила.
Само же изменение, точнее расхождение в терминологии, имеет очень давние корни, кабы не со времен Ломоносова (первый опыт русской грамматики, прямо скажем - не очень удачный).  Видимо, связано с тем, что в церковнославянской грамматике принято относить к первому склонению существительные мужского рода (2-е "школьное" склонение), а ко второму - женского. Но и там есть изрядная путаница. Гимназистов в большинстве так и учили, строго по этим принципам, а "школьников" - всякого рода ремесленные училища, ЦПШ и другие типы образовательных учреждения, которых в Российской Империи было множество - как придется. Когда же после революции 1917 г. пересматривали гимназические методики, как-то не подумали о том, что школьная практика стала отличаться от академической.
Вот все что могу сказать. Только не говорите, что это "правила склонения", это методика преподавания, правила в этой части неизменны.